# Migrate old Bitcoin Core wallet to Trezor

Tags: bitcoin-core, mnemonic-seed, trezor, private-key-export, wallet-import

I have an old [Bitcoin Core wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/download), and recently bought a trezor.
I wanted to use it, but I am unsure how to migrate it. While I can access it with my password, I do not know how to find its 12-word recovery seed (If ever there was one).

1. Do I have such a recovery seed?
2. Is there any other way I can migrate my wallet to the trezor? (Other than creating a new wallet and transferring funds from the existing one to this new one)
3. Can a Trezor hold several bitcoin wallets simultaneously? (Suppose I created a new one, and later discovered I can also access the old one through it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have such a recovery seed?

No. Bitcoin Core does not use mnemonics nor is the seed exportable.

> Is there any other way I can migrate my wallet to the trezor? (Other than creating a new wallet and transferring funds from the existing one to this new one)

No. The only way to migrate is to send a transaction that transfers your Bitcoin to your Trezor.

> Can a Trezor hold several bitcoin wallets simultaneously? (Suppose I created a new one, and later discovered I can also access the old one through it)

No.